# Where to find the most valid databases about the ranking of countries in research and scientific production?

Tags: online-resource, ranking, scopus

Where to find the rankings of countries in research and scientific production?

For example, how can I find out the ranking of a particular country in the number of scholarly essays? What are the most credited websites for such data?

I need such data because I am doing a research on the rate of scientific production of a particular country.

Comment: I'm curious to know your interest in this. Are you doing specific research into this? Looking for a good place to study? Other?

Comment: @Buffy I am writing a paper on the rate of scientific production of a particular country.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Sorry I can't help you. But adding context like that to your question might draw answers that will.

Comment: It's a subjective question, so "most valid" isn't well defined.  For instance, you could look at the number of scientific articles (I don't think "scholarly essays" is the term you want), the number of Nobel prizes, the economic value of scientific patents, etc.  I'm guessing that you're willing to settle for "most popular" instead.

Comment: Please see my answer below. Note that it is focused on publications, which might or might not be a good proxy for scientific production, depending on various factors (e.g., scientific domain). For a more comprehensive review of the subject, you have to analyze other types of scientific artifacts, some of which are mentioned by @DavidKetcheson above.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you haven't made any effort to find information in question, which is easily available online. To illustrate, just a very brief Internet search resulted in the following arguably relevant sources: [SCImago Journal & Country Rank - International Science Ranking](https://www.scimagojr.com/countryrank.php) as well as [Nature Index - Country Outputs](https://www.natureindex.com/country-outputs). Note that *Nature Index* is a much less comprehensive resource, since it is based on "selected group of 82 high-quality science journals". Thus, it is likely less representative, though it might still be representative enough, depending on how representative those 82 journals are. On the other hand, *SCImago Ranking* is based on *Scopus* database and advertises the coverage of 5000+ publishers and citations across 239 countries.

Obviously, if you are serious about your research, you have to perform a comprehensive search for relevant sources (as well as relevant papers) and analyze their quality before using any of them to draw any conclusions.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Web of Science and then search by author country. It unfortunately doesn't look like you can cover the entire database like this, but something like this would at least give partial results:

1. Go to Web of Science.
2. Enter a generic search term, such as "Science". If you're looking after a specific field, even better, use terms appropriate for that field. You can also refine by publication year if you wish.
3. From the results page (I hit 1,596,792 results in the Web of Science Core Collection), select "view all options" at the bottom, followed by Countries/Region.

As of time of writing, the top five countries for the above search are:

- USA (460,271)
- England (125,914)
- Germany (116,557)
- Japan (116,384)
- People's Republic of China (94,438)